# Arrange divs inside parent - align right div to top

Tags: css, html

I have the following where I want the right div to align to the top of the parent, but it's just not happening for me..

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="center">Center</div>
    <div id="left">Left text here...</div>
    <div id="right"><img src="image.png" width="75" height="75" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
  width:50%;
  overflow:auto;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:#aaaaaa;
  vertical-align: top; 
}

#left{
  width:100px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:#aaaaaa;
}

#right{
  float:right;
  width:100px;
  text-align:right;
  vertical-align: top; 
  border-style:solid;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:#aaaaaa;
}

#center{
  float:left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width:100px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:#aaaaaa;
}
```

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/w3Gcb/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you swap the `left` div with the `right` one, then the `right` div goes to top:
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3Gcb/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="right"><img src="image.png" width="57" height="57" /></div>
 <div id="center">Centre</div>
 <div id="left">Left text here...</div>

</div>
```

In Css

```
#right{
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align: top; 
    border-style:solid;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#aaaaaa;
}
```

Try this...

Answer (score 1):

Add one more div like this code:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="mid">
<div id="center">Centre</div>
<div id="left">Left text here...</div>
    </div>
<div id="right"><img src="image.png" width="57" height="57" /></div>
</div>
```

and give the CSS to mid class as following:

```
.mid{
    float:left;
}
```

This will work properly.